# Selecting text between two square brackets with str_extract

Tags: r, stringr

I have some variable labels that look like this.

How do i extract the text between the square brackets using stringr

```
var1<-' [I don\'t think public officials care much what people like me think.] 
For the following questions, please indicate whether you strongly agree, agree, 
disagree, or strongly disagree.'
var1
library(stringr)
str_extract(var1, '\[.\]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to use a regex lookaround to match all characters that are not a closing square bracket that follows an opening bracket

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(var1, "(?<=\\[)[^]]+")
#[1] "I don't think public officials care much what people like me think."
```

#### data

```
var1 <- " [I don't think public officials care much what people like me think.] \n\t\tFor the following questions, please indicate whether you strongly agree, agree, \n\t\tdisagree, or strongly disagree."
```